# Source Tree Commit and Push

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I badly need help for this one.

Scenario:
I have 2 computers literally 2. Now the 1st computer has already source tree and the 2nd one has just a newly installed source tree. I'm both using my 1 account on both source tree. The problem is that on the 1st computer I already committed and push some file but it doesn't show on my 2nd computer.

I copied all the settings from my 1st computer but still not working.

[1st Computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iubym.png)

[2nd Computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz8Ro.png)

Help, please.

Comment: How you cloned in 2nd computer ?

Comment: Did you try to pull down the changes in 2nd computer

Comment: i just copied the path that's in my 1st computer then paste it to the 2nd computer .

Comment: Try `git pull` in the repository of 2nd computer

Comment: I tried sir but the problem is like this i have a branch on my 1st computer which is pk/mobile origin/pk/mobile (graphic quality settings) - this is newly committed and pushed on the 1st computer and below that is pk/mobile origin/pk/mobile (New Method for Android Conversion)  . Now on the 2nd computer pk/mobile origin/pk/mobile (New Method for Android Conversion)

Answer (score 1):

Do git pull in terminal or use the pull button in Sourcetree toolbar. See: https://confluence.atlassian.com/get-started-with-sourcetree/get-started-with-sourcetree-847359026.html for more Sourcetree usage help.

Comment: i can't pull it out because i can't see it .
the problem is like this i have a branch on my 1st computer which is pk/mobile origin/pk/mobile (graphic quality settings) - this is newly committed and pushed on the 1st computer and below that is pk/mobile origin/pk/mobile (New Method for Android Conversion) . Now on the 2nd computer pk/mobile origin/pk/mobile (New Method for Android Conversion)

Comment: You may not have committed on your 1st computer do git status using the terminal in the repository in the 1st computer. If it says Changes to be committed, you not have committed anything. If it says Changes not staged for commit, you may not have added the file. Also check your .gitignore if it's ignoring your file.

Comment: I will edit my question with a picture of it so i can make it through everybody.

Comment: open terminal program(CMD, Terminal, iTerm or the like) in repository directory and type in git status. This would be a good tutorial for you to learn git basics: https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Comment: already find it . I have unstagged files . But i already commited the files that i wanted only to be commited. I edited my question sir.